# updating url without refreshing of webpage

Tags: jquery

I got a page that is displayed within an iframe. It contains a link that opens a page using ajax. ie I am updating part of a webpage. It works fine but the url is not updated. How to update the url such that it does not refreshes the page.

Answer (score 0):

During success of ajax method.
put this inside the success method:

```
jQuery.param.querystring(window.location.href, 'valueA=321&valueB=123');
```